# Join with wildcard

Tags: sql, oracle

Table1

```
|------------------------------------------------------------|
| Para_1  | column_A     | column_B        | column_C        |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 3007576 | abc          |                 |                 |
| 3007879 | ab           |  fg             |                 |
| 3007880 | ad           |                 | x               |
| 3007900 |              |                 |                 |
|------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Table2

```
|------------------------------------------------------------|
| Para_2  | column_A     | column_B        | column_C        |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 100     | abcd         |  fgh            | xyz             |
| 200     | abc          |  fg             | z               |
| 300     | ab           |  g              | xy              |
|------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Expected Results:

```
|------------------------------------------------------------|
| Para_1  | column_A     | column_B        | column_C        | Para_2
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 3007576 | abc          |                 |                 | 100
| 3007576 | abc          |                 |                 | 200
| 3007879 | ab           |  fg             |                 | 100
| 3007879 | ab           |  fg             |                 | 200
| 3007880 | ad           |                 | x               | null
| 3007900 |              |                 |                 | null
|------------------------------------------------------------|

select table1.*, table2.Para_2, table1.column_A
from table1
left outer join table2
on table2.column_A like ('%'||table1.column_A||'%') 
and table2.column_B like ('%'||table1.column_B||'%')  
and table2.column_C like ('%'||table1.column_C||'%') 

where table1.column_A is not null
and table1.column_B is not null
and table1.column_C is not null
```

the above code seems not sufficient.. any idea?

Comment: The WHERE clause wont pass any table1 rows at all.

Answer (score 0):

remove where clause because in each row in your sample data there is at least one null column value with the 3 column A,B,C so it filtered all

```
select table1.*, table2.Para_2, table1.column_A
from table1
left outer join table2
on table2.column_A like ('%'||table1.column_A||'%') 
and table2.column_B like ('%'||table1.column_B||'%')  
and table2.column_C like ('%'||table1.column_C||'%')
```

Comment: That produces 8 lines, not the wanted 6.

Answer (score 0):

This produces your expected result:

```
select table1.*, table2.Para_2
from table1 left outer join table2
on  table2.column_A like '%'||table1.column_A||'%' 
and table2.column_B like '%'||table1.column_B||'%'
and table2.column_C like '%'||table1.column_C||'%'
and coalesce(table1.column_a, table1.column_b, table1.column_c) is not null;
```

As you can see, this is almost what you had. But your `where` isn't needed, just an extra last line on the `on` condition. That extra line can also be written perhaps more clearly like this if you don't like the `coalesce`function:

```
and not (table1.column_a is null and table1.column_b is null and table1.column_c is null);
```

Or:

```
and length(table1.column_a||table1.column_b||table1.column_c)>0;
```